# Merging sub branch into master after parent branch has been merged into master already

Tags: git

I created `feature_A` branch from master and then I had to create another `feature_B` which is depending on feature_A (which is not yet merged into master).

Now I merge `feature_A` into `master` and work further on `feature_B`.

Finally, I am ready to merge `feature_B` into `master` as well. When trying to merge changes I got a lot of merge conflicts. I wonder what is the best process to avoid conflicts and still have a nice git/PR history of changes?

Comment: When merging `feature_A`, did you squash-merge?

Comment: Never merge something into the master branch, if it is not working properly yet. what you could have done, was to merge the branch feature_A into feature_B. then you still have the branch feature_A, and the branch feature_B with the features of branch feature_A

Comment: @eftshift0 yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you did a squash-merge when merging `feature-A`, no wonder. The easiest way to get out of the mess is to rebase the `feature-B`-only commits on top of `master`:

```
git rebase last-commit-of-feature-A-as-in-feature-B feature-B --onto master
```

That should work.... Now, *why* you landed in this mess is because you squash-merged `feature-A`.... it's not like it's forbidden, just be aware that git *does not* record any information about the original commits of `feature-A` being merged into `master` so, now that you want to merge stuff from `feature-B`, git sees that you probably have differing changes from 2 different branches: code that you developed in `feature-A` that was *modified* in `feature-B` and the code that is already merged from `feature-A`... hence: **conflict**.

As a side comment, it wouldn't have happened if you had merged *for real* (instead of squash). This is not to say that you should not squash (squash is fine... as long as it's not long-lived branches..... because you hit *this* exact problem), just that you have to be careful about the implications.